# Finding Cdf from the pdf

Tags: probability-theory

I have to find the cdf F(x) of a random variable X>0 with pdf satisfying the relationship
f(x)=αF(x)(1-F(x))
I cannot figure out how to solve it. Can anyone please help me regarding this?
$F(X)=\int_{0}^xf(x)$
$=\int_{0}^x(\alpha(F(x)(1-F(x))dx$
$=\alpha[F(x)\int_{0}^x(1-F(x))dx-\int_{0}^x(\frac{(dF(x)}{dx}\int{0}^x(1-F(x))dx)dx]$
$=\alpha[F(x)\{x-\int_{0}^xF(x)dx\}-\int_{0}^x(f(x)\int_{0}^x(1-F(x))dx)dx]$
$=\alpha[F(x)\{x-\int_{0}^xF(x)dx\}-\int_{0}^x(f(x)\{x-\int_{0}^xF(x)dx\})dx]$

Now it has become complicated. How will I go further? Or is this the correct way to solve it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I have tried it. I wanted to write it here but the format is not right. How do I fix that?

Comment: Have a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a quick tutorial on MathJax.

Comment: Hi, please check the question again.

Comment: Hi, this is totally wrong. You cannot take $F(x)$ out of integration, since it is not constant with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = F(x)$ then $y' = f(x)$ and your equation becomes
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = ay(1-y) \iff a\ dx = \frac{dy}{y(1-y)}
$$
Now integrating yields
$$
ax+C=\int a\ dx = \int \frac{dy}{y(1-y)}
$$

Can you use partial fractions on the RHS and finish?

**UPDATE**

So you are correct, integrating the RHS yields
$$
\int \frac{dy}{y(1-y)}
 = \int \frac{dy}{y} + \int \frac{dy}{1-y}
 = \ln|y| - \ln|1-y|
 = \ln \left| \frac{y}{1-y}\right|
$$
Note that since $y = F(x)$, we know $0 \le y \le 1$ and so $|y| = y$ and $|1-y| = y$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
ax+C     &= \ln \left| \frac{y}{1-y}\right| = \ln \left( \frac{y}{1-y}\right)\\
e^{ax+C} &= \frac{y}{1-y} \\
e^C e^{ax} &= \frac{y-1}{1-y} + \frac1{1-y} = \frac1{1-y} - 1
\end{split}
$$
Can you solve this for $y$ to get $F(x)$?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. F(x) is a function so can I solve this one in this way? I mean dy becomes dF(x) and I also have the range of the x so how I am gonna solve it

Comment: If I solve the equation of yours, I get ax=ln(y)-ln(1-y)=ln(y/1-y).Is it correct?

Comment: That's correct so far -- but don't forget your constant of integration! Now you need to convert this to make $y$ the subject (write it in the form $y = \cdots$ where the right-hand-side does not contain $y$, and you got your solution.

Comment: So, as dy becomes dF(x) so the range of x becomes automatically the range of F(x). I mean the equation will be,  $\alphax + c = \int_{o}^{F(x)}\frac{1}{F(x)}dF(x)-\int_{0}^{F(x)}\frac{1}{(1-F(x))}dF(x)$ like this?

Comment: @IsmatBintaIslam please see the update

Comment: Thanks for simplifying the answer.  Yes, I have got the F(x)